# Time Series Python : "Key Error" `start` argument could not be matched

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, time-series, arima

> I have trained data set with ARIMA model ,while predicting I am
> struggling with below error.

- KeyError: 'The `start` argument could not be matched to a location
  related to the index of the data.'

### train and valid indicate trainning and validation data set..

```
Code:
model = ARIMA(train, order=(2, 0, 0))
model_fit = model.fit(disp=1)

start_index = valid.index.min()
end_index = valid.index.max()

#Predictions
predictions = model_fit.predict(start=start_index, end=end_index)
```

Comment: Can you supply some minimal data to reproduce the error? What is the output of `valid.index.min()`, `valid.index.max()`, `train.index.min()` and `train.index.max()`? What is the type and frequencies of `valid.index` and `train.index`?

Comment: @DanielR above problem is solved . i have added answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you could find some NA values in the data set.
Filling those data points might get rid of the error.

Answer (score 1):

This error comes when there is missing value against date time in train data.